# Warning in Apache log: Cannot get media type from 'x-mapp-php5'

Tags: apache-2.2, httpd.conf

I have no idea what is causing this issue, but it seems to be related to the displayed file (just a simple index.php to print phpinfo) being in an aliased directory. Any suggestions what I can do to avoid the warning?

Here's an excerpt from my httpd.conf:

```
<Directory "<dir with broken php>">
    Options Indexes FollowSymLinks ExecCGI Includes
    AllowOverride All
    Order allow,deny
    Allow from all
</Directory>
Alias /smartersoftware/ "<broken dir>"
<FilesMatch \.php$>
    SetHandler application/x-httpd-php
</FilesMatch>
```

The last three lines were required to make php work at all (which I found a bit strange, and it may or may not be related to my problem).

Adding a `AddType application/x-mapp-php5 .php` didn't change anything.

Comment: What's your httpd.conf like?

Answer (score 2):

Try to find and remove/comment

```
AddType x-mapp-php5 .php
AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php
```

from your apache configs **and** .htaccess file.

Answer (score 0):

I would guess you have to add the addhandler in httpd.conf `AddHandler x-mapp-php5 .php`
http://httpd.apache.org/docs/1.3/mod/mod_mime.html#addhandler

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, but this doesn't change anything. As I understand addhandler, it just tells Apache that .php files are to be handled by x-mapp-php5. However, the error seems to indicate that it doesn't know what to do with this kind of file.